# Cocoa Model View Controller: where to do calculations

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I’m working on a piece of software which takes user input, does a lot of calculations on it, and then shows numbers and graphs based on the calculation results. I consider the MVC approach as good as possible. Here are my questions:

1. Where should I store user input (which will be shown in a table view)? Should it be stored in the needed `ArrayController` in the controller class or in an additional array in the model (class)? What I understand so far is that the information should be stored in the model.
2. Where should I do all of the necessary calculations, the output of which is used for the graphs in the view? Should these be done in the model or in the view controller (class)?
3. Does it make sense to have a separate controller class for table views in a nib? Right now I handle these data via my `ArrayController` in the corresponding window controller (class).

I’m asking pretty general questions because I understand that the MVC approach is independent from the code, but I have no problems with showing more specific code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the data array together with the calculation code in a class: the model.  The view controller would then read user input and place it in this model class.  This is good object-oriented design, keeping the data and its operations nicely together while keeping it totally free of UI-related code.

If the calculations won’t take much time, you can perform them in the main thread, so that your view controller calls a model method, which returns the result. Or, depending on the shape of your data, the model might make the result available with other methods and/or properties.

If the calculations might take longer, you should consider running them on a lower-priority thread inside the model, using [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)’s `dispatch_async()`. You don't want to block the UI for too long — around a second would be the limit, I would say. In this case, it would be best to add a ready block to the model’s calculation method so that the model can notify the view controller when the calculations are ready.  Don’t forget to run this block on the main thread, to prevent UIKit operations in the view controller from being messed up. (Let me know if you need details or code for anything I’ve mentioned above, but most of it should be easy to find on Stack Overflow or elsewhere.)

Finally, a single view controller for your NIB that contains a table view is the way to go. You’d typically place UI functionality (e.g. a graph) in a `UIView` subview, rather than in an extra `UIViewController`. Then you can place the subview on your NIB (or add it programmatically in the view controller).

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I store user input which should be shown in an table view. Should it be stored in the needed array controller in the controller class or in a additional array in the model (class)? What I understood so far is that the informations should be stored in the model.

The controller class should read it and store it in a model class. The view and model don’t speak to each other directly.

> Where to do all the necessary calculations which output is taken for graphs in a view. Should that be done in the model or in the views controller (class)?

In the controller, absolutely.

> Does it make sense to have an separate controller class for table views in a nib? Right now I handle these data via array controller in the corresponding window controller (class).

Yes, that makes sense. You can use a table view controller, as well — you can have as many controllers as you find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Most iOS implementations — including tons of tutorials that I have seen — do not strictly follow the MVC approach. In other words, the `UIViewController` subclass (or `UITableViewController` subclass) serves as the object that controls the view (V) *and* as the controller itself (C).

Technically these controllers are rather the view layer.

Your `UITableView` expects its controller to be the data source delegate, which means that it has to conform to the related data source protocol. Practically, the view controller often assigns `self` as the data source delegate (or IB assigns the File’s Owner, which usually will be the view controller).

To answer your questions:

1. I would say that the data should be represented in the model. For supporting the table, you might use some `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` structure (with index paths) that refer to objects in the model or that contain copies of the data within the model. If you have a dedicated controller, then it should be linking the model’s data to the view’s data.
2. All calculations that have to do with business logic should be done in the controller. If you decide to follow the established pattern of having a view controller that serves both purposes, then that would be the place for your calculations. Calculations that directly affect appearance (colors, `x` and `y` values for drawing, respectively, width and height values, etc.) should always be done in the view controller.
3. As I said before, it is rather common to use (or abuse) the view controller (the window controller is a view controller) as the controller according to the MVC model. I have decided to follow that approach so that I can easily integrate code snippets from tutoreals or Stack Overflow answers. But in the end, it is up to you. Using the window controller, however, is *only* advisable when you have a single-view application. As soon as you start using navigation view controllers for pushing views, tab bars, etc., you should (ab)use the related `UIViewController` subclass, if you’re not using a dedicated controller object.

Comment: Hello Hermann thank you for your answer. So even if I would open another window to show results (tables and graphs) you wouldn't use a separate window controller but handle the data straight to the controllers for the view (to show graph) and maybe another controller for the table showing results.

Comment: Well, that depends on what you mean by "window controller". There is only one UIWindow in an iOS App. (Unless there are additional screens attached to an iPad, I think ... ) I guess you refer to UIViewControllers. A single UIViewController usually controlls all the views that are visible at a time. Usually means it can be done differently. Each view may even have its own view controller. But to keep things simple. In most cases calculations will be done within the view controller and view geometry (layout) will be done there too.